# Creating Dummy Variable in SAS Enterprise Miner

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

Can any one suggest as to how can we create custom dummy variables in SAS Enterprise Miner?
For eg say I have a variable Var1 & I want to create a dummy variable Var2 when

```
Var1 >=1 
if Var1>=1 the Var2=1; 
else Var2=0;
```

Can this be achieved using SAS miner?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Modify> Transform Variables.